# How to change character when first character dies ?,Change Character Model mid game in UNITY3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine, character

I'm making a shooting game in which I want to change the character when my current character dies. I have made till the point where I can shoot and kill my current character. So, can anyone help me with the script on how to change to the 2nd character in mid-game..

Comment: The easiest thing is probably to create a Prefab of your 2nd Character and then when the player dies destroy the game object and instantiate the prefab at the position of the old character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[SerializeField] GameObject character1; // Prefab
[SerializeField] GameObject character2; // Prefab

void Die()
{
    SwitchCharacter();
}

void SwitchCharacter()
{
    Destroy(gameObject);
    if (gameObject == character1) // Is this GameObject character1?
    {
        Instantiate(character2);
    }
    else if (gameObject == character2) // Is this GameObject character2?
    {
        Instantiate(character1);
    }
    else 
    {
        Debug.LogError("Not a character1 nor 2");
    }
}
```

Now set character1 and character2 to their prefabs in the inspector.